# How to take user input and convert it to an array using python

Tags: python, split, termux

How to take an number input from user and split it's digits and use each digit separately

*For example*
If user enters '''4568'''
The code should split 4568 into 4,5,6,8

Comment: Pls show what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension over the user input.

```py
values = [int(i) for i in input()]
```

Note that this code doesn't handles cases where user puts non-digits characters in his input. To deal with this case, you would prefer to write :

```py
values = [int(i) for i in input() if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: No need to convert the input to a list.

Comment: @Pedro Maia how would you proceed to use each digit separately, then ?

Comment: Iterating over a string does exactly that.

Comment: @PedroMaia oh, you are right. That's a mistake for me. I'm gonna edit my message.

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` it to `int`, and convert the `map` to `list`.

```
digits = list(map(int, input()))
```

If you want to make sure only numbers are accepted add a `filter` to the `input`

```
digits = list(map(int, filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), input())))
```

Comment: As already suggested, this could fail in case of non integer user input

Comment: @Buzz - that's fine. That was not part of the question. I answered the question.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong ;)

Comment: @Buzz - I added in a digit filter.

Answer (score -1):

Convert it to string, iterate to string and get each character as an integer.

```
# Input from the user
inp = input()
digits=[]
for c in str(inp):
   try:
       digit=int(c)
       # Populate the list with the last digit obtained
       digits.append(digit)
   except:
        # I'm assuming you don't need to worry about any other non integer character
        pass
```

Or in one line, **BUT pay attention that if any non integer character is present into the input, the map fails**:

```
inp = 1234
digits = list(map(int, list(str(inp)))
```

Where `list(str(inp))` splits the string-converted input in the list of its characters, `map` applies the transformation to integer to each element of the latter list, eventually the conversion to list return your desired array

EDIT: I was writing the code while the comment were being written. I've now integrated the direct `int` suggestion to map function

EDIT2: a nitpicky edit to allow for an actual user input instead of a test variable. This does not change the substance at all.

Comment: Or just `list(map(int, list('12345'))) `.

Comment: This does not work. You don't make the appropriate conversions nor use the proper types.

Comment: This code is wrong on many levels.

Comment: Let light them up

Comment: This is still wrong and all over the place. The question was regarding user input, not some number that you convert to a string. Then you just toss in a solution from the comments that is entirely different than your approach. Also, you don't have to wrap the string in a list. Strings are already iterable.

Comment: Though pertinent, your point does not change the core of the answer, since the actual issue seems to be the obtaining of a list of integers out of an integer variable. I can put the `inp=input()`, and I'll do it and you're right, but this won't change the substance at all. Moreover, the last edit was clearly a slip.

Comment: As I explained into the edit I was writing the second solution while the other users where writing the comments. Actually I was testing on an online compiler before delivering the code. That's all. Only subsequently I noticed the comments, again, as already written.